# jinja2 format filters - Need to create columns

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, string-formatting

I need help, please. I need to create text columns and this filter is not working. This prints just one space between the text columns:

`{{ "%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s"| format(eachUser['address'], eachUser['login'], eachUser['user'], eachUser['hostname']) }}`

I take that the filters are not the same as those for format() in python; so, is there a list of filters anywhere that can be used to format a string like this ^ , correctly?.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I will appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: you could have a look at creating a table in html and place the variables in the right location, and use css for table design?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @gittert. It's an option I will take into account. Do you know I can find a list of format() filters that can be used in jinja?

Comment: Format function is to be used as placeholder for variables or keywords. It is not totally clear to me what you try to accomplish, i think you want some kind of columns with same column width? Hence my suggestion to use a table, or have a look at your use case. Normally fields in 1 column, max 2, works way nicer on a website (google for design best practices).

Comment: Indeed, 'columns with same column width' is what I am looking for. I followed your suggestion and the values I wanted are now inside table cells. I am now working on adding a button at the end of each row. That button will allow the user to perform an action. That action will be in a python function in the back-end.

Comment: Well done and if any help is needed, jusk ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using jinja2 filters to format the string, I created an HTML table and looped through the variables I needed to display them correctly. Thanks to @gittert for the suggestion!